# Error calling function: "argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

Tags: c++

I was assigned a program that needed a array of 25 doubles. Then needed to be flipped and displayed. I cannot seem to get the flipArray function to work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int NUMSCORES = 25; 
//double getData(double &myArray);
void flipArray (int arr[]);


int main(void)
{   
    int scores[NUMSCORES], i;
    for(i=0; i<NUMSCORES; i++){
        cout << "Please enter scores #" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> scores[i];
    }

    cout << "Your test scores:\n";
    for(i=0; i<NUMSCORES; i++)
        cout << "\tTest score #" << i+1 << ": " << scores[i] << endl;

    flipArray(NUMSCORES);
    return;
    }

void flipArray(int arr[])
{
    int j;
    for (j=NUMSCORES-1; j>=0; j--)
        cout << arr[j] << "\t";
}
```

Comment: "argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

Comment: ...and...on what line does it say the problem is?  If you include the error message and the line number, then you will write a clearer question and perhaps figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: When passing arrays to functions, always pass either the capacity or size too.

Comment: I think you're sending incorrect parameters to your flipArray() function.. it expects an array of ints and you're sending an int... .I may be wrong

Comment: In the future, you should include your error message with any questions, since they tend to make it obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Also, if the assignment is about an array of doubles, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
flipArray(NUMSCORES);
```

Your problem is that your argument is the number of scores (an `int`), not the array (which will be passed as an `int*`). Try this:

```
flipArray(scores);
```

Comment: @user1810514 When an answer solves your problem, you can click the up arrow next to it to make the answer as helpful (you can mark as many as you want), and you can choose one answer to mark as "accepted" with the checkmark. This helps other people looking at answers in the future and also gives people who help you points (yay internet points!).

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells the whole story:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
prog.cpp:22: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void flipArray(int*)’
prog.cpp:23: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘int’
```

These two lines are wrong:

```
flipArray(NUMSCORES);
return;
```

In the first line, you are passing in an `int`, namely the size of the array, when you should be passing in the array itself.

In the second line, you have failed to specify the return value from `main`.

Try:

```
flipArray(scores);
return 0;
```